# php loop with countdown

Tags: php, foreach

Say i start my counter at 400. How would i execute a foreach loop that will run backwards until 0?

pseudocode

```
$i = 400;
foreach(**SOMETHING**)){
//do stuff
$i--;
}
```

Comment: Actualy you answered a question with complex code there is also a for loop. You didnt decrement it but incrementig it everyone should look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656731/php-function-for-generating-mm-dd-yyy-and-hh-mm-dropdowns-with-current-date-selec/1656812#1656812

This question is in my opinion spam and should be flagged

Comment: The question was how to do it **with foreach**, which is hard enough to do for most people as most answers show.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
for($i = 400; $i > 0; $i--)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

**other ways to do it:**

```
$i = 400;

while($i > 0)
{
  // do stuff
  $i--;
}
```

or

```
$a = range(400, 1);

foreach($a as $i)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: The decrementing while is very nice.

Answer (score 6):

In case you really want to iterate backwards over an existing array you can use **array_reverse()**:

```
foreach(array_reverse($myArray) as $myArrayElement){
  // do stuff with $myArrayElement
}
```

Answer (score 4):

how about a for loop

```
for($i = 400; $i > 0; $i--)
{
    //stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` is used for iterating over sequences or iterators. If you need a conditional loop then use `for` or `while`.