# How can I fetch recent email using imap function php?

Tags: php, imap

I am trying to fetch email using imap function which return very old email. Following script i am trying

```
$imap = @imap_open("{mail.******.com:143/novalidate-cert}", $sEmail, $sPwd);
    $message_count = @imap_num_msg($imap);
    for ($m = 1; $m <= $message_count; ++$m){
     $header = @imap_rfc822_parse_headers(imap_fetchheader($imap, $m));
     $email[$m]['from'] = $header->from[0]->mailbox.'@'.$header->from[0]->host;
    }
```

Currently above function return email in ascending order, so that's why very old emails (2015's Email) are coming first. So is there any way to get recent email first.

Comment: Reverse the loop, start with $message_count and count down to 1.

Comment: @Piskvor Can you show the example please

Comment: you count up, here: `for ($m = 1; $m <= $message_count; ++$m)` - reverse this.

Comment: @Piskvor I am sorry I don't get your point.

Comment: What is the behavior of your code in the block I have pointed out? What happens to `$m` in each iteration?

Comment: @Piskvor `$m` is parameter as `message number` to `imap_fetchheader()` function

Comment: In this part of the code: `for ($m = 1; $m <= $message_count; ++$m)`, you start by setting `$m` to `1`; then, if it's below `$message_count`, you increment it (`++$m`).

Comment: You want to do the opposite: set $m to `$message_count`, and if it's > 1, decrement it in each iteration.

Comment: Can you write a code line for me please

Comment: Writing a `for` loop is hard? Okay, look at this answer - the first option they use there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2089282/19746

Comment: ( Note that the ordering of messages in inbox is not guaranteed - you may want to look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-sort.php instead )

Comment: mr. @Piskvor give you more than enoght. 
But also be sure what you are understanding difference between Pre-increment(++m) and Post-increment(m++)

Comment: @ABelikov: How is that relevant here? (Not at all.) The value of `$m` is only incremented at this point in code, but the returned value is not used. If this were `for ($m=0;(++$m) < $max; )` or `for ($m=0;($m++) < $max; )`, your warning would be meaningful (yes, this usage would be silly - I was trying to show an example without veering too far from the original code).